# Brew: uninstalling all version of a package

Tags: qt, homebrew

I am trying to uninstall `qt`.
I did `brew uninstall qt`, and it uninstalled the version 5.9.0, but it says that:

> 4.8.7_2, 5.8.0_1 2 are still installed

I want to delete them as well.
Is there a way to uninstall with `brew` all the versions of a package?
Thanks in advance!

OS: `Mac El Capitan`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
brew uninstall --force qt
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall qt@4.8.7_2 qt@5.8.0_1
```

Both of these will probably warn that there are still dependencies, for example on my machine:

```
$ brew uninstall qt
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.0
because it is required by gnuplot, octave, poppler and pyqt, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies qt
```

You don't use --force, but add these reverse dependencies to the list. For my example above:

```
brew uninstall qt@5.14.0 gnuplot octave poppler pyqt
```

You can then check with `brew list` if there are any other remnants you want to remove.